# dynamic dropdown internationalization

Tags: spring, jsf-2, el

I'm developing an application in JSF + Spring and I got a question about dynamic internationalization.

My xhtml file have this:

```
<h:outputText value="#{msg['propertyType.apartment']}" />      1.//THIS ONE WORKS
<p:selectOneMenu id="propertyType" value="#{bean.propertyType}">
<f:selectItems value="#{global.propertyTypeList}" var="list" itemValue="#{msg['#{list.key}']}" itemLabel="#{msg['#{list.value}']}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>                                         2.//THIS ONE DOESNT WORK
```

My ManagedBean have this code:

```
private Map<String,Integer> propertyTypeList = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
public GlobalBean() {
propertyTypeList.put("propertyType.apartment", 1);
propertyTypeList.put("propertyType.warehouse", 2);
propertyTypeList.put("propertyType.office", 3);}
```

And finally my bundle file have this:

```
propertyType.apartment=Apartamento
propertyType.warehouse=Armazém
propertyType.office=Escritório
```

The point number 1 works fine and shows `Apartamento`. The section number 2 shows `propertyType.apartment`, `propertyType.warehouse` and `propertyType.office` in the dropdown.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: if I had this "#{msg[list.value]}" doesn't work either...

Comment: That's a different problem. See http://stackoverflow.com/tags/selectonemenu/info how to get started using selectone components the right way.

Comment: The dropdown is well constructed, only it doesn't show the word in the bundle file.